# How can I add list to another list? PANDAS df.loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I'm Newbie to Pandas.

My df is a CSV with accounting information, I have variables with a list of accounts inside them, and I want to add them to another variable first and then use df.loc

```
df = pd.read_csv('2021BALANCE.csv')

menor = (df['account_1'] < 10000)  # just filtering 


#LIST OF ACCOUNTS inside variables 
  
assets = ['account_1', 'account_2', 'account_3']
liabilities = ['account_6' , 'account_4']
profits = ['account_20' , 'account_21']

#THIS VARIABLE already have accounts, and I want to add the accounts above to it.

all_accounts = ['account_9345', 'account_234623' ,assets, liabilities, profits]


df.loc[menor, all_accounts]


TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

There are tons of variables with accounts inside them, I just put 3 here in order to simplify, and I want all of them in just one variable **all_accounts**  so I can use **df.loc[menor, all_accounts]** .

Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: From the names of your variables it's not clear what you want to do. If you simply want to put all the variables in one big list you can use the `append` method e.g. `all_accounts.append(assets)`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to "merge" the lists into a single flat list, you need to use the spread operator (https://how.wtf/spread-operator-in-python.html) to "unpack" the lists you're trying to insert into the new one. Otherwise you're nesting the lists, causing the .loc to throw the error.

Try using this in the declaration of "all_accounts":

```
all_accounts = ['account_9345', 'account_234623' ,*assets, *liabilities, *profits]
```